# How to don't start entrypoint command on "docker-compose up"?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have multiple Docker containers in a project and I use `docker-compose up -d` to start containers.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yml
version: "3"
services:
  httpd:
    image: 'nginx:stable-alpine'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - ./laravel:/var/www/html
      - ./.docker-config/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - backstage

  php:
    build:
      context: ./.docker-config/dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./laravel:/var/www/html:delegated
    networks:
      - backstage

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    env_file:
      - ./.docker-config/mysql/mysql.env
    ports:
      - '33060:3306'
    networks:
      - backstage

  composer:
    build:
      context: ./.docker-config/dockerfiles
      dockerfile: composer.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./laravel:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - backstage

  artisan:
    build:
      context: ./.docker-config/dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./laravel:/var/www/html
    entrypoint: ["php", "/var/www/html/artisan"]
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - backstage

  npm:
    image: node:14-alpine
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ["npm"]
    volumes:
      - ./laravel:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - backstage

  phpunit:
    build:
      context: ./.docker-config/dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./laravel:/var/www/html
    entrypoint: ["vendor/bin/phpunit"]
    networks:
      - backstage
```

As you see, I defined `entrypoint` for the `phpunit` container, but I don't want to start the phpunit when I run `docker-compose up -d`.

How can I do that?

Comment: If you only want to start one specific service you can do `docker-compose up <servicename>`

Answer (score 2):

You can scale service that you don't want to run to 0

`docker-compose up --scale phpunit=0 -d` And it will not start container for phpunit service as stated in [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)

You can also check [compose profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) for more options on excluding certain services in your docker-compose file.